# Stop users from being able to save a site as a favorite

Tags: sharepoint

I have a html file that plays a video than directs the user to a SharePoint 2013 site to log their name as watched it. The problem I have is people are saving the site so they don't have to watch the video. Is there a way to prevent them from doing this?

Comment: Not the ideal solution, but you can check the origin, and see if they have come from your website.

Comment: Not sure I follow? I want to stop internal users from saving the site page to their browser favourites.

Comment: You can't stop them from bookmark it. But you can redirect them if the `referer´header is empty. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer